# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider

Tags: angularjs

I've set a service using Angular named uIdentity. But, when I try to call it this way:

```
app.controller('foo', function(uIdentity){});
```

I get this error message:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: uIdentityProvider <-
>   uIdentity

How do I fix this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
app.controller('foo', ['uIdentity',function(uIdentity){

}]);
```

or with more items

```
app.controller('foo', ['$scope','uIdentity',function($scope, uIdentity){

}]);
```

Basically you are defining the name of the objects as they are defined and they will be mapped in sequence. Another example:-

```
app.controller('foo', ['$scope','uIdentity',function($x, y){
   //$x is $scope and y is uIdentity

}]);
```

If you get error in-spite of that you have something wrong in the uIdentity itself.

In general you may want to make it a habit to always use that syntax. It also makes your code resilient from uglification/minification/obfuscation.

Make sure you define the dependencies

```
app.service('uIdentity', [function(){

}]);
```

Comment: Added one more example with $scope in the answer since I cannot format code in the comment. The sequence is important.

Comment: Please post a plunker or update the question with the other parts

Answer (score 0):

You have to ensure, that your provider is in the same angular.module like your application OR your application depends on the module your provider is located in.

If your `uIdentity`-provider is part of a module called `myIdentityModule` e.g. your application needs `myIdentityModule` as a dependency.

Your code might be sth like

```
angular.module('app', ['myIdentityModule'])
```